# Changing Day_of_WEEK not updating Day_of_month (Android Calendar)

Tags: android

today is Tuesday and date is 24 
but when i set the Day_of_WEEK to Monday the day_of_month still remain 24 
i want it to move automatically to next Monday because Monday of this week has passed.

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, hour);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are directly setting the day of the week without adding to the numerical day. If you do not know how many days to add directly, run it through a loop that adds a day until it is a Monday.

```
while (Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK != Calendar.MONDAY)
{
  Calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
}
```

Comment: Its changing the date but loop is not terminating because Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK is a constant flag having value equals to 7

Comment: IT Worked like this while (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != day)
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);